# House annual price

Tags: problem-solving, percentages

[image: The question]

Based on the question above may I know whats the answer and how to get the answer. I'm confused whether after 2 years is the 2nd year or the 3rd year. Thanks.

Comment: After 1 year the value is $1.08 \cdot x$, and after two years it is $1.08^2 \cdot x$. Set that to the given value, and solve for $x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After two  years means $2$ years not $3$ years. Thus you have to raise $(1.08)$ to the second power not the third power.

You need to solve $x(1.08)^2 =139968$ for $x$ to find the original price of the house.